# Debugging Apache/Django/WSGI Bad Request (400) Error then aliasing sub-path

Tags: python, django, apache, alias, wsgi

I have a django projet running on domain example.com juste fine.
I want to Alias one particular app to example2.com but, when I disable django Debug, I keep getting Bad Request (400) Error.

I use django 1.7.7 with python 2.7.9 on debian jessie. example.com and example2.com are both served by apache 2.4.10 with WSGI module 4.3.0.

In apache global scope configuration I have :

```
WSGIDaemonProcess tracking user=www-data group=www-data processes=2 threads=15  python-path=/path/to/projects/tracking/ display-name=wsgi-django-tracking
```

In example.com vhost I have:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/projects/tracking/tracking/wsgi.py
WSGIProcessGroup tracking
<Directory /path/to/projects/tracking/tracking/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

In example2.com vhost I have (note the **/myapp** on at the end of both paramater of the WSGIScriptAlias instruction):

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /path/to/projects/tracking/tracking/wsgi.py/myapp
WSGIProcessGroup tracking
<Directory /path/to/projects/tracking/tracking/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

In django settings I have:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["example.com", "example2.com"]
```

With `DEBUG=True` everything works great. When I set `DEBUG=False`, example.com keep working but when I try to access http://example2.com/myapp all I get is :

```
Bad Request (400)
```

Nothing usefull shows up in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` nor `/var/log/apache2/access.log` so I'am a little confused.

**Thank you for your help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-check that the hostname is present in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` entry.  I know you said it is, but `400 Bad Request` is exactly the error you'd get if the hostname were missing from the setting.

Please check `ALLOWED_HOSTS` again.

Comment: Thanks fot the answer, I have checked, the hostname is present. Moreover, I have exactly the same behaviour then setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Comment: Make sure that your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` isn't overwriten later in code.

Comment: This is possibly the worst error handling I've ever seen in a widely-used project.  Generic 400 errors in the `ssl_error_log` and no output to the configured application log, no indication anywhere of what went wrong or how to fix it.  For shame, Django!

Comment: John, thanks for the answer.   This was my problem!

Answer (score 0):

please check your wsgi.py

this is correct code.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/Happ')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Happ.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

for see logs you must add

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```